# How to make virtual devices on GNS3 be able to ping the physical host

Tags: networking, bridge

Disclaimer: this is a duplicate question, I asked [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50317/36279) and then [that question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50508/36279) on another community, but I'm still not clear how to solve my problem. I just don't get it, so here I am asking a question again, maybe someone can help me on this community.

---

The problem is explained in the above two questions. Basically, I have developed a topology on GNS3. From within my virtual devices, i.e. PC and router on GNS3, I can ping any device on my real network, **except my very own physical computer hosting the GNS3 topology**. Also, from within my real host computer, I can ping any device on the network **except the virtual devices like PC and router on GNS3**.

---

I know the reason for the above observation: the host computer and virtual devices on GNS3, they all **share the same MAC address**, so the ARP packets sent from within the physical host cannot figure out the MAC address of the virtual devices on GNS3 and vice versa, as explained on [this thread](https://gns3.com/discussions/virtual-router-can-t-ping-local-):

> When trying to ping your host, the VM sends an ARP request as
>   broadcast (destination MAC is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff), like "Who has
>   192.168.1.20? Tell 192.168.1.80". This message is sent to your switch/router which floods the broadcast to all ports **except** the port
>   it has received the broadcast from; i.e. your local PC will never
>   receive the broadcast originated from itself, even if the packet came
>   from a VM.

---

Well, now I know the reason but I don't know how to resolve the problem. It is suggested by a community member: `There are many videos and descriptions just a quick Google search away`, strangely however, I don't seem to be able to find any useful material to solve my problem. Can someone please help me.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/50606. You also have been told why you can't ping at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/50318 and your own answer at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/50507. Asking the same question until you get the answer you want (rather than the correct answers you're getting) doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't seem to want to believe the answers you've being given.

Comment: @roaima I voted to close this question too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the answer to this question [on another community](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/50606/36279).